# What is time? What is its definition?

Tags: classical-mechanics, experimental-physics, time

What does **time** really mean? What is its definition according to physics? And also, why is speed, acceleration is measured with respect to time only, we could have also used some other reference point too, but why only time? Why was there a need for time to be defined? I mean people could also say oh, it's day, it's night, why did they start the concept of time? Can existence of time be proved, as every other concept of science can be proved experimentally?

Comment: Some of these statements aren't actually true, not every concept in physics has a precise definition or explanation and not every concept can be "proved experimentally". In many cases it isn't even how one would go about doing either of those. The precise role of time is different in various ways across different models in physics. This question is probably not satisfyingly answerable and is probably off topic.

Comment: Have you tried the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy? https://plato.stanford.edu/contents.html#t

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the answer is non-unique and would fit a book to write.

Comment: We needed a more precise measurement than "day" or "night"

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time

Comment: Time is what a clock measures.  This is a "working definition".   It's how one measures time. From a practical point of view, is any other definition needed?

Comment: There is a talk by C Rovelli about time. I did not get if time exists or what is. But I got that one can waste 8 min 59 sec of it. :)) https://youtu.be/n5iAqKt1uhA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much of physics is concerned with mathematical models of change. In such models you need to take into account the change in the quantities concerned (eg positions, energies) and the rate at which the changes occur. Time is a dimension used in physics to quantify in a relative way the rates at which changes occur.

A second is defined in terms of a change that occurs in nature, namely a certain transition within a caesium 133 atom- the second is the time taken for 9,192,631,770 of those changes.

If we did not have the concept of time within physics, we would be unable to compare different types of change. Take speed, for example. It is a measure of the extent to which a change in position happens, taking into account the rate at which it happens. If your position changes by 100m in ten seconds, and mine changes by 100m in five seconds, the change in distance is the same, but there is an important difference between the two cases, namely that your change in position happens at a different rate than mine. If we did not take time into account, we would have no way to model the movements. No end of calculations in physics involve rates of change that must be compared or taken into account in some way, and time is the factor we use to quantify the rates at which one thing happens relative to another.

There are endless debates about the philosophy of time, which you can easily research on line, but within physics it is simply a counter that allows us to compare in a quantitative way the rates at which different event happen.

At one time it was thought that the counter of time ticked away at the same rate everywhere, but we now know that it depends upon relative motion and gravity. The transition of a caesium atom that defines the second would happen at a different rate on the Earth's surface than it would in a satellite orbiting the Earth. Relativity allows us to predict the magnitude of the changes with great precision, predictions which have been repeatedly confirmed by experiment.